# Is it possible to allow users to only edit a SharePoint list through a PowerApp, but to have view permissions of the full list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp

I have a PowerApp that allows all users to write to a list. There is an approval process where an administrative team is reviewing entries, etc. However, from a reporting standpoint, we would like for all users to be able access certain views of the list as read-only users. That is, we don't want someone to be able to go into the list and edit in grid view...they should only make edits to their own records through the PowerApp (which triggers review processes).

Is this possible? My understanding is users have to have write permission to the list for the PowerApp to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the item-level permissions settings to achieve this (you can find these settings by going to the list settings and then advanced settings). You can configure the settings so that users can only:

- Read items created by the user
- Create and edit items that were created by the user

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, users should have edit permission for the list and PowerApps forms.